# Quaternions algebras whose class groupoid is actually a class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quaternion-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and let $\mathcal{O}$ be a maximal order in $A$. Like the case of number fields, we can define an equivalence relation to define something similar to the class group of number fields. We denote it by $\mathcal{C_O}$. Unfortunately, here $\mathcal{C_O}$ does not form a group, it just forms an Abelin groupoid.

Let's restrict $A$ to be a 4-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, i.e. $A$ is a quaternion algebra. Are there some conditions, under which $\mathcal{C(O)}$becomes an Abelian group?

Comment: How do you form a monoid?  I know how to form a groupoid...

Comment: @Kimball You are right. I was mistaken about the name of that kind of objects. I meant groupoid.

Comment: There are different ways to generalize the commutative case.  You get a group if you look at 2-sided ideal classes, or you can define a group structure on 1-sided ideal classes using a weaker notion of "stable equivalence".  But maybe the answer you are looking for is: when all 1-sided ideal classes are represented by 2-sided ideals, i.e., type number 1.

Answer (score 1):

See section 20.7 of my book (http://quatalg.org).

The reduced norm gives a surjective map (of pointed sets) from the class set of a quaternion order $\mathcal{O}$ to a certain class group of $\mathbb{Z}$ (defined by local norms).  This map is an isomorphism when the quaternion algebra is indefinite, because strong approximation applies.  In other words, for all indefinite quaternion orders, the class set is naturally an abelian group by the reduced norm map!

For definite quaternion orders, it turns out that there is an explicit finite list of orders where the above surjective map is bijective.  This includes the list of orders with class number 1 (section 25.4), and a few others ([https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/defcancel-09302019.pdf](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/articles/defcancel-09302019.pdf)).